# How to view the UIImage via image viewer in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am developing in **Objective-c**. I have a **WiFi media device** and it has many image file. The WiFi media device will turn on the AP mode. So the iPhone can connect via WiFi.

After the App connect to the **WiFi media device** , it read the all media file that store on the **WiFi media device**.

I want to view the image file which on the **WiFi media device** but without download. I can get the Url of image file like the following:

**`NSURL url = http://192.72.1.1/DCIM/100_NOML/SNAP0008.JPG`**

I covert the url of image file to **UIImage** via the following code.

```
UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:urlImage];
```

I want to view the UIImage via some viewer.

But how to view the UIImage in objective-C ? Which Objective-c API can view the UIImage ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean to say that you want to view the image on your device: iPhone or iPad?

Comment: Have you made `IBOutlet` connection with `UIImageView` object? There are lot of tutorials all around.

Answer (score 2):

Your code(NSURL to UIImageView) is right.
But I think wrong url address.

If you check code(NSURL to UIImageView), Url change to http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/ca0f847878fc4be5bac353194231ef81.png

By any chance, do you miss this code?
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

Answer (score 0):

There is a one Apple Quick look framework available to see all type of image/documents anywhere rather than downloading those to your side and show it.

I've attached the link of Apple's quick look framework guidance here, hope this will help you definitely.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
-(void)doViewImg{

    UIButton *imgViewBttn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    imgViewBttn.frame=frame;
    //your img
    UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    [imgViewBttn setImage:urlImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imgViewBttn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
    imgViewBttn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
    imgViewBttn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgViewBttn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [imgViewBttn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeImageViewBttn:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview: imgViewBttn];
    [urlImage release];
}

-(void)closeImageViewBttn:(id)sender{
    UIButton *imgViewBttn=(UIButton*)sender;
    [imgViewBttn removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It will place UIButton as big as your screen then set your image on it. Touching image (i.e. button) will remove it.